# Async HttpRequest in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

I used the below code for making a `HttpWebrequest` and read response from server.

```
private async Task<bool> ReadUrlAsync()    
{      
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(request_url) as HttpWebRequest;                
    request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    var factory = new TaskFactory();
    var task = factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

    var response = await task;
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string data;
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    responseStream.Close();
    return true;
}
```

But i am not sure about is this is the right way , since i can see

```
var response = await task
```

and one `TaskFactory` instance inside method.
So is any way to write this code without `Taskfactory` or a seperate `await` inside the function

Answer (score 2):

Awaiting a `FromAsync` task is fine. I usually create an extension method so that the `FromAsync` is in its own method, but it does almost exactly the same thing as you're doing here (the [standard pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ApmToTap) is to use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` instead of `new TaskFactory().FromAsync`).

Note that a more modern approach is to use [`HttpClient` from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http), which simplifies the code significantly:

```
async Task<bool> ReadUrlAsync()
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(request_url))
    {
      var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that you want the response explicitly, e.g., to check response headers. If you don't need it, you can simplify further:

```
async Task<bool> ReadUrlAsync()
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    var data = await client.GetStringAsync(request_url);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May this will help you

```
private void ReadUrlAsync()
    {
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(request_url) as HttpWebRequest;                
        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);
    }

private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  {
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
     using (Stream responseStream= response.GetResponseStream())
       {
         string data;
         using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
          {
            data = reader.ReadToEnd();
          }
       }
  }
```

Comment: IS there any request.ReadAsync() kind of extension available.?
In case of reading from file we are using .ReadToEndAsync(); so any similar way exists ?

Comment: Issuing a GET request on a url and read response from the url